# Custom Order Reports - Orders Purchased From Field - Fraud

Tags: orders, customer, reports

When I ***export a report via CSV for Customer Orders***, under the field `Orders Purchased From`, it states `Admin, Default, Admin` - this applies to all my known fraud orders.

*Is this a default response for the `Purchased From` field?*

Or

*Does it mean the Default Admin manually entered the order?*

I am not real familiar with Magento and searching frantically for answers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The purchased from field should be populated with the store that the user purchased the order from. In the case of an admin order this will be the store that you select on the second step of ordering.

The page looks as follows in Mage 1.9

[image]